# How to customise UICollectionView Cell to show image grid as shown in attachment?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, storyboard, uicollectionviewcell

I want to show images as shown in the attachment. How can I do this using storyboard and objective c?

Based on the image count, the cell size needs to be adjusted.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: Image grid view]

Comment: Hi - nice pictures. I think you need to look at compositional layouts for this.

Comment: But it is available in iOS13+ only :(

Comment: What is your minimum iOS? If below 13 you can use horizontal collection view and use size of collection view cell to get something similar.

Comment: iOS 9. Ok will try

Comment: Ok - here is a bit of an outline ... I *think* you need to scroll horizontally and the first image's sides is double that of the others. That will give you a large first image and then the tiles next to it. It is actually really easy even in iOS 9, but may not be exactly what you want.

Comment: I added two collection views and defined the cell counts based on the image count.

Comment: No I think you need two collection view *cells* - one large one and then one small one. Eventually you'll have one large photo and lots of small ones. You could even do it with just one view and set the size programatically ... but actually if you want to hard code the number of photos you can do it that way as well but it is clumsy ... you have two collection views on screen ...

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

This answer applies to the original question with a single layout based on a large first image and smaller latter images.

This is really easy ... I did not bother with iOS versions and what I give below needs a lot of additional work, but at least it will give you the idea.

**The storyboard**

In the storyboard I really just set up two items in the collection view. One large and one small picture. You could easily do it with one, here I use two as then I can load the image in storyboard and need not bother with configuring the cells.

Hopefully the image below will help you understand what I mean. Also note the *horizontal* scrolling.

[image: storyboard setup]

**The collection view**

This is bare bones. Of course it needs work. Especially I do NO cell configuration but dequeue and return the cell straight without any configuration. You need to configure each cell by loading the image that should be displayed for it.

The two cell types I define in storyboard are called `imgLarge` and `imgSmall`. Note I use the same as item identifier as well.

The most important thing here, that really makes it work, is the last message, where I return two different sizes for the two different cells.

```
#import "TestCollectionViewController.h"

@interface TestCollectionViewController () < UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout >

@end

@implementation TestCollectionViewController

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.delegate   = self;
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ( indexPath.row )
    {
        return [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"imgSmall" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        return [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"imgLarge" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegate>

- ( CGSize ) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat h = collectionView.bounds.size.height;

    if ( indexPath.row )
    {
        return CGSizeMake( h / 2, h / 2 );
    }
    else
    {
        return CGSizeMake ( h, h );
    }
}

@end
```

This is actually the second version. The first version just used constants here. Since they are calculated, to make it work, you need to set all the spacing and insets to 0 in storyboard.

**The result**

Voila!

[image]

I mentioned that this is the second version. The previous one looked slightly different as you can see below. I kept the image, for the code of the earlier one just look at the history of this post.

[image: result]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your explanation and the example. I have edited the question for my full requirement. Is a single collection view with the size adjustment mentioned by you enough here? Kindly give your suggestion.

Comment: Yes a single one will do - you can just add some logic to that method where the size is calculated ... I gave a sample here earlier but it was wrong but idea will work, just calculate size based on number of images.

Comment: You will probably also want to create a variable ```w``` with the width and then you just use the width and height (w and h) to return an appropriate size. The rest is just simple mathematics ... if there is such a thing ...